# "Copy to selected" dose not work with curves ? or Nurbs?

Tags: properties

I want to set "preview U resolution" of all the selected curves to 48.

1. I select all the curves and shift select one curve change its
   "preview U resolution" to 48.
2. Set "preview U resolution" to 48. [image: "preview U resolution"]
3. Then right-click to "Copy to selected" [image: "Copy to selected"]

Copy selected is grayed out! Why ? does it not work on curve objects? or Nurbs ?

Note: it works fine on mesh objects

Comment: Probably a bug...

Comment: I don't think so, As Campbell mentioned on irc, **Copy to Selected** doesn't support a number of things yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i learnt of copying through script from another post. And here is what i have changed to suit this purpose.

```
import bpy
active_obj = bpy.context.object

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if obj != active_obj:
        # resolution U
        obj.data.resolution_u = active_obj.data.resolution_u 
        # We could also access other proerties like bevel
        obj.data.bevel_depth = active_obj.data.bevel_depth
```